# I am trying to use double pointers and am unable to link them. here is the example,

Tags: c, pointers

In C programming,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
/* POINTER TO POINTER*/
 int d;
 int *k;
 int **p;
d=12;/* this is the value of our variable d*/
k=&d;
/*we have assigned our pointer a # to assign address of our variable.*/
p=&k;/* we have now assigned stated that the value of our second pointer is the value of the first pointer*/
printf("the value of our variable d is %d\n",d);
printf("the value of our variable k  is %d\n",*k);
printf("the value of our variable p is %d\n",**p);
   /* all these dislays the values of variables and not address.*/
   /* to print addresss we use*/
printf("the address value of our variable d is %p\n",&d);
printf("the address value of our variable k is %p\n",k);
printf("the address value of our variable p is %p\n",p);
printf("the address  value of our variable p is %p\n",&k);
printf("the address  value of our variable p is equal to  is equal to k  %p\n",&k);



return (0);
```

the output looks like this

```
the value of our variable d is 12

the value of our variable k  is 12

the value of our variable p is 12

the address value of our variable d is 0x7fff2692a434

the address value of our variable k is 0x7fff2692a434

the address value of our variable p is 0x7fff2692a438

the address  value of our variable p is 0x7fff2692a438

the address  value of our variable p is equal to  is equal to k  0x7fff2692a438
```

I am thinking all the address location should be equal but are not.

I tried to use # to assign the first point but it failed to compile.

kindly help.

Comment: What is (an example of) your expected output? The variables `d`, `k`, and `p` has separate locations. You may want to try `*p` to retrieve the address of `d`.

Comment: How did you try to use `#` to assign? It won't appear in normal C expressions.

Comment: It's not clear why there is any confusion here.  Given these assignments, you have the following equalities:  `d`, `*k`, `**p` are equal, `&d`, `k`, `*p` are equal, and `&k`, `p` are equal.  There's no more to it than that.

Comment: am trying to use double pointers.                                                                                      I have 3 variables two of which are pointers. I want the address of int d to be eaual to address of k and p.

Comment: And of course, `#` isn't a C operator.  It's used as a prefix for preprocessor directives, but that's all.

Comment: @ Tom karzes I want to create a variable say d then the 1st pointer *k and a second one **p. i want to assign the address of d to be stored by pointer k . also i want to assign the assined address to k to p. printing them out should display similar address.

Comment: as shown above the address of var d and the 1st pointer k arethe same. I am now asking why is the second pointer p address not equal to the first two?

Comment: `%p\n",p);` -> `%p\n",*p);` Also `%p\n",&k);` doesn't make sense at all. And that's about all there is to say.

Answer (score 3):

I think your confusion comes from the distinction between the *value* of a variable and it's *address*.

First, you should make a distinction between:

- The *value* of the variable, which is what the variable contains
- The *address* of the variable, which is numeric value representing variable's location in memory

Whenever you do a simple assignment on a variable, in your case

```
d = 12
```

The *value* `12` is copied to the variable `d`. So now the variable `d` will contain the value `12`.

To obtain the address of any variable you use the `&` operator. You can check the value and the address and the value of the variable `d` like this:

```
printf("The value of d is: %d\n", d);
printf("The address of d is: %p\n", &d);
```

Same thing happens when you declare the variable `k`. The only difference is that variables of type `int *` will contain addresses as *values*. This is where it can get a little bit confusing: `k` is a variable, so it has an address, but also this variable *stores* the address. To better demonstrate this we can print it's value and address:

```
int *k = &d;
printf("The value of k is: %p\n", k); // same as &d
printf("The address of k is: %p\n", &k); // different from &d
```

Since `d` and `k` are different variables, they will be stored in different locations, so these variables will have different *address*. However the *value* of `k` will be equal to the *address* of `d`, since you explicitly assigned it to `k`.

With pointer values you can *dereference* them. This will use the *value* of the pointer and return the value at the memory location pointed by that pointer. Since `k` points to the address of `d`, dereferencing `k` will return the value stored at address `&d`, so we can expect the code to print 12.

```
printf("The value k points to: %d\n", *k); // should print 12
```

The variable `p` is again, another variable, so it will have a different address from the address of `d` and the address of `k`.

```
int **p = &k;
printf("The address of p is: %p\n", &p);
printf("The value of p is: %p\n", p);
printf("The value of k is: %p\n", *p);
printf("The value of d is: %p\n", **p);
```

You will expect the first line to print address that's distinct from `&d` and `&k`, because after all all three of `d`, `k`, and `p` are three *different variables* stored in different locations.

Since you assigned the value of `&k` to `p`, the second line will print the address of `k` (`&k`).

The third line will print the value that the address of `k` *points to*, that is, the value of `k` itself, or `&d`.

And finally the fourth line will print the value that `&d` points to, or the value of `d`, that is the value `12`.

I encourage you to play around with pointers in a debugger (built into visual studio). You can open Watch and Memory windows and look at the memory raw to better see the values and addresses and how they play along.